# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module React JS Antd

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, antd, package.json

For bundle size optimization instead of getting components from the lib folder, I am importing it from the es folder.

Example:

```
import Modal from 'antd/es/modal';
```

So on writing test cases it is giving me the following error

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I have gone through related questions possibly duplicate but couldn't resolve it with my current implementation as it does not fall to **global scope**.

So my question is, Is there any way to achieve this

I tried referring to the following links too but no help,

https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/package.json#L21
https://medium.com/@fredriccliver/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-69182014b8c6

Comment: First if all, you may not need to use deep imports that because `antd` import will use ES modules in Webpack build. This can save you the trouble. Otherwise you'll have to exclude antd/es from Jest transformIgnorePatterns to transpile them. This can bring other problems.

Comment: @EstusFlask Okay, but in case I go with the deep import option for learning purpose how can I transpile them?

Comment: Something like this, https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2081#issuecomment-699558143 . So in your case it will be `"transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!(.*antd/es)/)"]`.

Answer (score 24):

Change

```
import frFR from 'antd/es/locale/fr_FR';
```

to

```
import frFR from 'antd/lib/locale/fr_FR';
```

fix this problem.

Comment: man I've had this problem on one of my pages for days. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I was facing the same issue with the Footer component.**

[image]

I dynamically added the Footer component and this is how I resolved this error:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const Footer = dynamic(
  async () => await import("../../components/footer/footer"),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]